# How to read the last row with SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, ajax, bar-chart

I want to read and display latest inserted value. My table contains same name contains different value. So I want to display the latest inserted value by selecting that name. Please help me.
My code is given below:

```
select Name, Debit, Credit From aTable where Name=@Name
```

Data Base:
I want display only the last record inserted into the table.

[image]

By using the above code the output is coming like the given below image:

[image]

I only want to display chart with the last inserted value on Hari's name(3000,20000)
Thank You.

Comment: The only way to do this and be sure it is correct is to have a column with the insert date time and sort by that descending using `ORDER BY insert_datetime DESC`

Comment: You could `SELECT TOP 1 ORDER BY [date entered column] DESC`, but you haven't shown any columns that indicate a date entered

Comment: u can use order by id in ur table

Comment: If you don't have a "Date Entered" column, but you do have an auto-number column, you could use that in the same way.

Comment: @rajeeshmenoth can you post the full query regarding to oder by id.

Comment: refer this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53071/how-to-extract-the-last-inserted-row-in-sql-server

Comment: Thank you to every one for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to add one more column as Id or Date 
then appy following query

```
select top 1 Name, Debit, Credit From aTable where Name=@Name order by Id desc
```

or

```
select top 1 Name, Debit, Credit From aTable where Name=@Name order by date desc
```

Comment: order by desc gives expected result

Comment: ID columns don't insure ordering -- The identity can be reseeded and it can also be overridden using `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` -- be careful when using and assuming.  I stand by my original comment as being the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Select the Max id of ur column:**

```
SELECT  MAX(Id) FROM Table_name
```

**Select ur table details:**

```
SELECT * from Table_name
```

**Put ur Max id into where clause**

```
SELECT * from Table_name where Id =(SELECT  MAX(Id) FROM Table_name);
```